# AEM: Display an Alert box after server side validation

Tags: forms, jsp, aem

I have a form in AEM. When the submit button is clicked control goes to forward.jsp. I have done some validations in forward.jsp and would like to generate on alert on the page once the validation is failed. How can I pass the alert to the page?

```
if(condition){
    // validation success
} else{
    // code for alert
}

FormsHelper.redirectToReferrer(slingRequest, slingResponse);
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to do the validation server-side, but show an alert client-side, I recommend you use JavaScript to make an AJAX call.  You could change your submit button so that when it is clicked, it fires an AJAX call instead of submitting a form.  See http://api.jquery.com/jquery.ajax/ for a description of how this could be done using jQuery, but other options would also work for making the AJAX request.

In the response to that AJAX request you can put whetever you need.  It can be a status code, a string of JSON, or a blurb of HTML.  You then would write client-side JavaScript to handle the response and do whatever is appropriate based on the given response--such as show an alert on the page.

An example of this sort of approach if seen at http://michaelsoriano.com/how-to-ajax-validate-forms/

Answer (score 0):

This topic is more complicated that you might think. Basically you can see sample implementation in the foundation components such as /libs/foundation/components/form/text/text.jsp. They all use the com.day.cq.wcm.foundation.forms.LayoutHelper#printErrors method to check if they are errors on field. This is happening over the com.day.cq.wcm.foundation.forms.ValidationInfo class which is set as request attribute in order to transfer the field state between the different classes. You can check also the com.day.cq.wcm.foundation.forms.FieldHelper class which performs actually the validation. Putting some sort of logic in the forward.jsp is the wrong ways